# java: why a char cost so many memories?

Tags: java

I know a char in java is 2bytes. but if load some chars in a list, they will cost 87B to save a char. the test is like the following:

There is a file "source" containing 995328 lines. every line is just a character:'a'. (so it will cost almost 2MB in java to save all chars).

There are two sleep method called in my source code and I use top command to check the memory usage at any moment.

The RSIZE value when running the first sleep(10000) method is 25M, and 108M when running the second sleep method. so per String(which is just an "a" ) cost:(108MB-25MB)/995328=87B. I don't know why a String "a" cost so many memory!!! Could any one can tell my why?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    File file = new File("source");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line = null;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Thread.sleep(10000); 
    while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
        list.add(line);
    }
    Thread.sleep(10000);

}
```

Comment: How do you know that a `char` costs 87 bytes (which sounds not plausible)? What was your method to measure this? Note also that a single `char` is something totally different than a `String` object that contains one character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Amir is right to say that there are better ways than top (for instance, [hprof](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/HPROF.html) is included with the JDK) to measure memory usage, but there are some deeper issues that confound your memory numbers.

1. You aren't closing either `file` or `br`.  This is the big one.  Each one of these objects is a wrapper around a bunch of native code to interface with your operating system's file I/O libraries.  Those resources include file handles and cached buffers, so some of the data you're reading from the file is counted twice in memory usage - once in the cache attached to `br`, and once in `list`.
2. Each string isn't really just a sequence of characters.  The JRE maintains a pointer to a character array, a start index, and a length, along with other data.  The pointer to the character array is 8 bytes, the start index is 4 bytes, and the length is 4 bytes.  I'm sure that I'm leaving out some fields, but even this conservative estimate gives 16 bytes of overhead for a string, ignoring the actual characters in the string.
3. The `list` variable has overhead as well.  There is a backing array, where each slot is a pointer (8 more bytes), and there are plenty of empty slots.  As the backing array grows to accommodate the lines, the `ArrayList` class leaves some extra space because the array resize (that is, create a new array and copy over all the elements from the old array) is expensive, and each of the empty slots is 8 bytes on a 64-bit system.
4. The numbers returned by top include garbage.  The garbage collector varies between JVM implementations and versions, but typically it collects new objects quickly and only collects old objects if there is memory pressure.  So all the extra arrays left over from resizing the backing store of the `ArrayList` are quite likely still in memory, and counting towards the top numbers.  Since those arrays are large to start with (most likely there is one that is at least 500K slots, each an 8-byte pointer), this boosts the program's total memory usage.

N.B.  I talked about 8-byte pointers above, assuming a 64-bit system.  On a 32-bit system, everything I said holds, except that pointers are only 4 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

I would not rely on top to calculate these numbers.  Why aren't you using something like [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) - which will tell you exactly how much memory is being occupied by your data structures?

`RSIZE` I believe reflects total resident memory, which would include the memory using by the JVM itself!  Aside from this issue, your benchmark does not take into account unreachable objects not yet collected by the JVM.  Using the profiler's heap snapshot triggers a GC, which does take this into account.

Answer (score 1):

You are not saving only the chars in the arraylist, you are storing one `String` instance per row in the file.

I haven't done these calculations myself, but according to [Neil Coffeys tutorial on string memory utilization](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/string_memory_usage.shtml), each string takes up:

> Minimum String memory usage (bytes) = 8 * (int) ((((no chars) * 2) +
>   45) / 8)

If your file contains one char per row, each string will cost you at least `8*((2+45) / 8)` = 47 bytes.

Add to that the cost of the arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

You are completely overlooking the costs of the Strings you are creating, and of the list, and specifically its growth policy. Check the Javadoc. The implementations of ArrayList I have seen inside grow the list by 50% when it overflows.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a garbage collected language, and so you can't look at the externally measured changes in virtual memory footprint over the execution of some code to estimate the sizes of data structures.  You are taking into account increments in the heap which could be due to the accumulation of garbage as well as due to the accumulation of garbage. Also garbage collection better if gives itself quite a lot more space than is necessary to represent the live set of objects, so that collection isn't so frequent. Generally speaking, garbage collection becomes slow if there is very little slack space. If the virtual machine kept its memory footprint close to the bare minimum required to represent all the objects, it would perform very badly.